# Move multiple existing git repos into one new parent repo

Tags: github, repository

I want to put several of my git repos into one main repo while preserving the commit history.
Is this possible and how?

I tried just putting all these repos into one main parent, doing `git add .`,  and then pushing.
But it shows [commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V05vE.png)

[image: commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules]

And when pushed on Github, the folders are like this and unclickable.

[image: the folders are like this and unclickable].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when pushed on Github, the folders are like this and unclickable

Yes: you have pushed **[gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), representing the SHA1 of the *nested* sub-repository.

But the main parent does not know *where* to get those nested subrepos, so GitHub display a white arrow without any link.

The better approach would be, in your local main repository, to use the [`git submodule` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), which would add *and reference* (in a `.gitmodules` file), those same repositories.

That supposes those children repositories are already pushed in their own remote Git repo hosting service, and addressable with a URL.